# How to prevent msdeploy from overwriting IIS site configuration on server stored in web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-8, msdeploy

I'm deploying using VS2017, and MSdeploy WMSVC seems to be overwriting my IIS site settings being deployed to.

The site settings, in IIS manager, has IIS Authentication panel, Anonymous Authentication Credentials set as Application Pool Identity.

[image]

After deployment, all requests get 401.3 unauthorized error, because the Anonymous Authentication Credentials setting gets set to user:

[image]

Clearly this is getting overwritten because of a clash between SERVER specific settings and DEVELOPMENT specific settings.

In any MSDeploy scenario, what strategy can we use to prevent the target IIS settings from getting walked on by Development server settings?  My first thought is, IIS first looks for site.config which would contain system.webService, then web.config updates/overrides any of those, ie `<handler remove key="xxx" />` and so forth.  Is this only solvable by XDT transforms?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution to solve this is using [web.config XDT transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations).
Since web.config file will also be published when deploy to the IIS server. If you have set the anonymousAuthentication setting in the web.config, it will use web.config setting instead of your server default setting.

Here is another solution(It will show the error page):

If you don't want to let the web.config to modify the default IIS setting, you could modify the feature delegation to disable override the setting from web.config.

You could find it from the IIS management feature:

[image]

Select read only:

[image]

Notice:
If you modify the Anonymous Authentication from the web.config. You will face below error:

[image]